# Set timer in android quiz application

Tags: java, android

I'm a beginner in android application. I want to make android quiz application with a timer. Every question has a timer and resets in every next question. How can I input countdown timer with my java activity?

Here's my code:

```
public class QuizHistoryActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private TextView countLabel;
private TextView questionLabel;
private Button answerBtn1, answerBtn2, answerBtn3;

private String rightAnswer;
private int rightAnswerCount = 0;
private int quizCount = 1;

static final private int QUIZ_COUNT = 10;

ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> quizArray = new ArrayList<>();

String quizData [][] = {
        {"Question random", "correctanswer",
                "choice a", "choice b", "choice c"},

        {"Question random", "correct answer",
                "choice a,""choice b","choice c"},
};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_quiz_history);

    countLabel = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.countlabel);
    questionLabel= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.questionlabel);
    answerBtn1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.answerbtn1);
    answerBtn2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.answerbtn2);
    answerBtn3 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.answerbtn3);

    //Create quizArray from quizdata
    for (int i = 0; i < quizData.length; i++) {

        //Prepare array
        ArrayList<String> tmpArray = new ArrayList<>();
        tmpArray.add(quizData[i][0]);
        tmpArray.add(quizData[i][1]);
        tmpArray.add(quizData[i][2]);
        tmpArray.add(quizData[i][3]);
        tmpArray.add(quizData[i][4]);

        //Add tmpArray to quizArray
        quizArray.add(tmpArray);
    }

    showNextQuiz();
}

public  void showNextQuiz () {

    //Update quizCountLabel
    countLabel.setText("Question #" + quizCount);

    //Generate random number between 0 and 14 (Quiz Array's size -1)

    Random random = new Random();
    int randomNum = random.nextInt(quizArray.size());

    //Pick ine quiz set
    ArrayList<String> quiz = quizArray.get(randomNum);

    //Set question and right answer
    //array format
    questionLabel.setText(quiz.get(0));
    rightAnswer = quiz.get(1);

    //remove "country" from quiz and shuffle choice
    quiz.remove(0);
    Collections.shuffle(quiz);

    //Set Choices
    answerBtn1.setText(quiz.get(0));
    answerBtn2.setText(quiz.get(1));
    answerBtn3.setText(quiz.get(2));

    //Remove this quiz from quizArray
    quizArray.remove(randomNum);
}

public void checkAnswer (View view) {

    //Get pushed button
    Button answerBtn = (Button)findViewById(view.getId());
    String btnText = answerBtn.getText().toString();

    String alertTitle;

    if(btnText.equals(rightAnswer)) {
        //Correct!
        alertTitle = "Correct!";
        rightAnswerCount++;
    }else {
        //Wrong
        alertTitle = "Wrong";
    }

    //create Dialog
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setTitle(alertTitle);
    builder.setMessage("Answer : \n \t \t" + rightAnswer);
    builder.setPositiveButton("Got It!", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
            if (quizCount == QUIZ_COUNT) {
                //Show Result

                Intent resultintent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ResultQuizHistoryActivity.class);
                resultintent.putExtra("RIGHT_ANSWER_COUNT", rightAnswerCount);
                startActivity(resultintent);
            }else {
                quizCount++;
                showNextQuiz();
            }
        }
    });
    builder.setCancelable(false);
    builder.show();
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

here is it

```
 CountDownTimer countDown;
countDown= new CountDownTimer(30000, 1000) {

     public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
         mTextField.setText("seconds remaining: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
     }

     public void onFinish() {
      //call nextQuestionMethod here
     }
  };
  countDown.start();
```

A **30 Sec** timer with **1 sec** tick , you can change these values according to your choice. Refer to this [link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html) for more details.

Comment: @jane in `showNextQuiz()` and when timer finishes show the popup or show next quiz.

Comment: it didn't refresh after next question  and direct to next question after i select the answer even it did not finish the timer

Comment: Here is what you can do , make and object for countdowntimer and then reset that object on next question

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Chronometer from the Android framework to show the time in the UI, and:

```
long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
```

At the beginning of the quiz, and at the end

```
long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
long timeTranscurredInMillis = end - start;
```

...to get the time that the quiz lasted.